How config nginx and php-fpm for laravel reverb
I'm having trouble launching Laravel reverb.
I have run my program with Docker, but I get an error.
my nginx config:
location /app {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
}

my env file:
REVERB_HOST=duchresidency.com
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=https

my docker compose:
nginx:
    build:
        context: "./docker/nginx"
    depends_on:
        -   php-fpm
    volumes:
        - $PWD/ssl/fullchain.pem:/etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem
        - $PWD/ssl/privkey.pem:/etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
        - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
        - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available
    ports:
        - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
        - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
    networks:
        - sail


php-fpm:
    build:
        context: "./docker/php-fpm"
    volumes:
        -   ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    networks:
        - sail
    expose:
        - "9000"
        - "8080"
        - "5173"

laravel-horizon:
    build:
        context: ./docker/laravel-horizon
    volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
        - ./docker/laravel-horizon/supervisord.d:/etc/supervisord.d
    depends_on:
        - php-fpm
    extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
    networks:
        - sail

You can see my code to create Laravel web socket.
Note: I have used cloudflare for DNS.
I tried many ways, but I did not get any results.

If you don't share the error, it is impossible to help...

Disable ssl in reverb - because reverb located behind two reverse proxies (nginx and cf).

@Maksim Thank you for answer, can you help how disable ssl for reverb?

@matiaslauriti the erorr is : WebSocket connection to 'wss://duchresidency.com/app/fsriv4vzymaa4lxbxxaz?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.4.0&flash=false' failed:
